# A quest for html.unescape("&nbsp")

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
import os
import html

a = html.unescape("home&nbsp;-&nbsp;study")
b = "test"
print(a)
s = (a, b)
print(s)
```

And this is my result:

```
home - study
('home\xa0-\xa0study', 'test')
```

Why does the result print like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, printing containers like `tuples`, `lists` and others *will use the `repr` of their items*. 
<sub>(In CPython, it was chosen to not implement `<container>.__str__` and instead let `object.__str__` fill its slot. The `__str__` of `object` will then call `tuple.__repr__` which then proceeds to call [*the `repr` of the elements it contains*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L294). See [PEP 3140](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/) for more.)</sub>

Calling the `repr` for a string with escape codes (such as `\xa0`) will, in effect, not escape them:

```
print(repr(a))
'home\xa0-\xa0study'
```

To further verify, try `print(s[0])`. By providing the `str` object in position `0` directly, python will invoke *its* `__str__` and escape the hex correctly.

Comment: Thank you your explain.I understand the reason now.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that the behaviour is only due to an implementation detail... this is not the case. It is expected that sequences define a `__str__` method in which the representation of the inner elements is obtained calling their `__repr__`. The implementation detail is that they decided to make `__str__` be the same of `__repr__` and avoided defining `__str__` explicitly since `object.__str__` simply calls `__repr__`. There was [a PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/) to try to change this and it was rejected.

Comment: @Bakuriu I can see how that's implied. Fixed the body up a bit to make it clear what evolves implementation details and what doesn't. Hadn't read that PEP, thanks!